# Accept self-answer after bounty

Tags: support, bounties, self-answer

I asked a question on stackoverflow ([Slow Databinding Setup Time in C# .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788215/slow-databinding-setup-time-in-c-net-4-0)), but in few days nobody had posted a solution for my problem in this question. I started a bounty and still got no solution. After few weeks, I had solved it myself. I posted my solution as an answer to my question, but am unable to accept it. Why can't I accept a self answer to my question? I have ~80% accept rate and if this answer was accepted I would have 100%. **What i can do about this?**

Comment: Upvoted your answer, now it is on the top of the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bounty system is no longer connected to the accepted answer system, finally!

See:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/